# JavaScriptで絞り込み。テーブル全体を絞り込み

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript(jquery)での絞り込みにトライしており、ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

一番下のコードのようにリストタグでの絞り込みはできますが、以下のテーブル全体を表示したり、非表示はできないのでしょうか？（赤のセレクトボックスを選択する場合、一度のテーブル全体を表示したまま、かぼちゃ、キウイのtableは非表示とする。）

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>いちご</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>種類</td><td>野菜</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>色</td><td>赤</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>かぼちゃ</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>種類</td><td>野菜</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>色</td><td>黄色</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>キウイ</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>種類</td><td>果物</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>色</td><td>緑</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

★ためしに、以下のようにtableで囲って書いてみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
<table class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="赤色">いちご 種類: 野菜 色: 赤色</table>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>JavaScript Practice</title>
  <style>
    .search-box_label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.is-hide {
    display: none;
}
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="search-box">
            <span class="search-box_label">種類:</span>
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="">ALL
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="野菜">野菜
            <input type="radio" name="kind" value="果物">果物
        </div>
    
        <div class="search-box">
            <span class="search-box_label">色:</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="赤色">赤色
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="緑色">緑色
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="黄色">黄色
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="赤色">いちご 種類: 野菜 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="黄色">かぼちゃ 種類: 野菜 色: 黄色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">キャベツ 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="赤色">さくらんぼ 種類: 果物 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">すいか 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="緑色">キウイ 種類: 果物 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="黄色">バナナ 種類: 果物 色: 黄色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="野菜" data-color="緑色">メロン 種類: 野菜 色: 緑色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="赤色">りんご 種類: 果物 色: 赤色</li>
        <li class="list_item" data-kind="果物" data-color="黄色">レモン 種類: 果物 色:黄色 </li>
    </ul>

  <script>
   var searchBox = '.search-box'; // 絞り込む項目を選択するエリア
var listItem = '.list_item';   // 絞り込み対象のアイテム
var hideClass = 'is-hide';     // 絞り込み対象外の場合に付与されるclass名

$(function() {
 // 絞り込み項目を変更した時
 $(document).on('change', searchBox + ' input', function() {
  search_filter();
 });
});

/**
 * リストの絞り込みを行う
 */
function search_filter() {
 // 非表示状態を解除
 $(listItem).removeClass(hideClass);
 for (var i = 0; i < $(searchBox).length; i++) {
  var name = $(searchBox).eq(i).find('input').attr('name');
  // 選択されている項目を取得
  var searchData = get_selected_input_items(name);
  // 選択されている項目がない、またはALLを選択している場合は飛ばす
  if(searchData.length === 0 || searchData[0] === '') {
   continue;
  }
  // リスト内の各アイテムをチェック
  for (var j = 0; j < $(listItem).length; j++) {
   // アイテムに設定している項目を取得
   var itemData = $(listItem).eq(j).data(name);
   // 絞り込み対象かどうかを調べる
   if(searchData.indexOf(itemData) === -1) {
    $(listItem).eq(j).addClass(hideClass);
   }
  }
 }
}


/**
 * inputで選択されている値の一覧を取得する
 * @param  {String} name 対象にするinputのname属性の値
 * @return {Array}       選択されているinputのvalue属性の値
 */
function get_selected_input_items(name) {
 var searchData = [];
 $('[name=' + name + ']:checked').each(function() {
  searchData.push($(this).val());
 });
 return searchData;
}
  </script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 解決しました。テーブルの絞り込みもできるようです！

Comment: ななみ さん> 解決された場合は、解決した方法を回答として投稿し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Comment: liのクラスを<table></table>にそのままつけたところ、テーブル単位での絞り込みができました。

Comment: 解決済みはどちらからできますでしょうか？

Comment: 「回答」欄に投稿してください。